# Google Chrome Extension - AJAX Callback not being fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a simple Chrome extension and trying to run an Ajax request after a tab is updated. Simply, every time a new domain is visited, the domain is checked to see if it is supported.

I'm having an issue with the Ajax callback; it's never fired. Success, error or complete, none of them are fired. To be specific, this is when the Ajax request is made within the chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener callback. So the below doesn't work:

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab)
{
    test();
});

function test()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'http://exampledomain.com/check.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {domain: 'test'},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus)
        {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

However, if test() is called outside of the listener, the callbacks are fired.

If I check the network in dev tools, every request is successful and the server returns the expected response. But if Ajax is called from within the listener callback, the response is never caught.

For clarity, manifest is below:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test Extension",
    "description": "Extension Description",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Popup Title"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "http://exampledomain.com/"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try using fetch or if it works in other extension api listeners.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @DanielHerr Thanks for your reply. Fetch certainly seems to be a good alternative which I can use. I will leave the question open as I am genuinely interested in to why the problem occurs.

Comment: Does it occur in other chrome extension api listeners?

Comment: @DanielHerr Just ran a quick test with chrome.storage.sync.get and yeah, the Ajax request seems to work fine. Callback is running.